# multiple basic slidetoggles in the same page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, slidetoggle

I use this code for a toggle :

```
    <script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> 
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>OPEN</h1></div>
```

I try to use several time this toggle in a same article on my website but it's not working.  I am not using jQuery but only javascript.
How can I use several time this toggle in a same article without getting a conflict ?

Comment: I tried to use function toggle(), function toggle1(), function toggle2()... but without success.
I tried to add a number also to "toggleText" and "displayTest" ... but without success.
Any idea ?

Comment: since no one else is replying... i am not js expert, but you can't use `toggle()` like that, because you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. you could pass `this` as an argument to `toggle()` and use it instead. also, correct declaration is `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Thank Marko, as I said to Nibra, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to just add a number. In order to make the toggle() function work with different elements, you have to provide the information about them to that function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle(id, link) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = document.getElementById(link);
    if (elem.style.display != "none") {
        elem.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    } else {
        elem.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleText', 'displayText');">hide</a> 
        <div id="toggleText" style="display: block"><h1>OPEN</h1></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="toggler2" href="javascript:toggle('secondText', 'toggler2');">show</a> 
        <div id="secondText" style="display: none"><h1>OPEN</h1></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Nibra for you help! I copied-pasted your code in my article but I am still getting an issue. Only one out of the 2 links work; when I click on the second one, nothing happens.

Comment: I tested the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDe8V/) - there it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nibra and for having taken the time to check. So it should be a conflict with Joomla since I have past your code directly in the source code of my article (exactly as you wrote) and I get the result explained above.

Comment: A conflict with Joomla is unlikely, I use such code regulary with Joomla. I'd rather guess that the function name `toggle` is probably chosen by another extension, too, so renaming it to something else could solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working ! Actually I made the test with some other javascipt on it, it was probably causing conflict because when I put your code in a new article it works fine. thanks a lot ! I did post a new question to add a slow effect on the toogle without jquery.  (cf détail : Code bellow to solve problem of the fist toggle that remained open)

Answer (score 0):

Code bellow to solve problem of the fist toggle that remained open. Thanks Nibra !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function toggle(id, link) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        var text = document.getElementById(link);
        if (elem.style.display != "none") {
            elem.style.display = "none";
            text.innerHTML = "show";
        } else {
            elem.style.display = "block";
            text.innerHTML = "hide";
        }
    }
    // ]]>

</script>
<ul>
    <li><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleText', 'displayText');">show</a>
        <div id="toggleText" style="display: none;">
            <h1>OPEN</h1>
        </div></li>
    <li><a id="toggler2" href="javascript:toggle('secondText', 'toggler2');">show</a>
        <div id="secondText" style="display: none;">
            <h1>OPEN</h1>
        </div></li>
    <li><a id="toggler3" href="javascript:toggle('thirdText', 'toggler3');">show</a>
        <div id="thirdText" style="display: none;">
            <h1>OPEN</h1>
        </div></li>
    <li><a id="toggler4" href="javascript:toggle('forthText', 'toggler4');">show</a>
        <div id="forthText" style="display: none;">
            <h1>OPEN</h1>
        </div></li>
</ul>
```